# How can I convert a csv file to a list in order to sort numerically

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNqta.jpg)I have a .csv file made from a python script which stores a score (integer) and a name which is a string, is there a way for me to sort this numerically, once converted to a list? I also can’t sort the items before they go into the csv file as I need there to be preexisting values within the csv file so I can output them in descending order. As the picture shows I have tried the map function but it says it needs to be an integer not a list.[Code + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNqta.jpg)

Comment: I am sorry for you but this site has rules about how question can be asked. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. Specifically, you are supposed to give you code as text so that it can be copied, and a sample input so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code and error *in the question itself*. Do not rely on external links being reachable by others, or on others to transcribe code from pictures to be able to test it. See the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Comment: Take note that your file contains winner score *and name*. Doing ``scores.append(row)`` appends both score *and name*, and ``map(int, scores)`` likewise attempts to convert each score *and name* to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you something like this:

File created by me:

```
1,hello
12,idontknow
33,foo
3,bar
0,fooo
7,baaar
```

And here is the code:

```
import csv

def csv_sort(file_path):
    opened_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    data = list(csv.reader(opened_file, delimiter = ','))
    return sorted(data, key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = csv_sort('path_to_your_file')
    print(results)
```

Results:

```
[['0', 'fooo'], ['1', 'hello'], ['3', 'bar'], ['7', 'baaar'], ['12', 'idontknow'], ['33', 'foo']]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I adapted it slightly as I didn’t want to use a sub program but the code itself was based on yours. Sorry if my ineptitude at asking properly meant you had to transcribe any code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Pandas library to play with your csv.
pandas.read_csv() will read your csv file and then you can use the function sort_values(by='name of the column') to sort your data set.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map int() to the list 'scores' instead to the item you want to cast to an int.

change

```
scores = list(map(int, scores))

list.sort(scores, , reverse=True)
```

to:

```
scores = list(map(lambda l:[int(l[0]), l[1]], scores)
list.sort(scores, key=lambda l:l[0], reverse=True)
```

and it should work.

Beside that the loop that creating 'scores' is unnecessary because you already converted the csv to a list in the line:

```
csv = list(csv.reader(open("HighScores.csv")))
```

Just change the variable name from 'csv' to 'scores' and you can delete the loop.